# Crop images in both sides on wordpress

Tags: php, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make add_image_size() crop from the top?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20923/how-can-i-make-add-image-size-crop-from-the-top)

When generating a thumbnail or featured image the wordpress resize the smallest side and then crop the largest side.  I need to make it crop both sides on **post thumbnail** or on **featured image** in functions (**preferable**). Any way to reach this using an wordpress **plugin** or **hack**?

Answer (score 0):

HELLO,

You can use below functions for `cropping`  Or `resizing` your images.

> add_image_size('news-thumbnail', 500,
>   200, true);

AND

> the_post_thumbnail('news-thumbnail');

you can also refer this [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8928/a-way-to-get-featuread-image-or-first-image-and-crop-on-the-fly-before-display).

Thanks.