# What is your take: TimThumb vs. WordPress Thumbnails? The great debate

Tags: post-thumbnails, timthumb

When it comes to excerpts, do you believe TimThumb or WordPress thumbnails is the way to go?  And why?  Answers will not be graded (but may be criticized).

Comment: Way to go for what? This question makes no sense to me without specific scope to measure against. I am considering closing it as "not constructive" or turning into community wiki.

Comment: I'd go with the WP way. I don't see any advantages in using TimThumb

Comment: @One Trick Pony - IMO the only thing TimThumb has that WP thumbs need is on-the-fly generation. I've had many situations where a new layout required new thumbnail sizes, having to re-generate WP thumbs is no fun. TimThumb doesn't play well with cache plugins though without significant hackery, so no go for me.

Comment: I'm all about the WP way. Anything WP can do, I stick with. I don't like bringing in external dependencies. The WP thumbnail feature may be a little weak right now.... but IMO it's not hard to add image sizes, and regenerate thumbnails if needed.

Comment: @Milo: that's not a feature, that's a bug :) If a thumbnail size is missing in WP you can regenerate it before it gets displayed on the screen

Comment: @Milo Take a look at my plugin here: https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the built in `<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>` function is much more flexible, easy and with less overhead. It does resize-crop, so I don't see a reason to go back to TimThumb (which I used extensively in the past).

Comment: I didn't even realize that function existed!

Comment: yes it's very nice I use it all the time. For instance: if you have a frontpage slider with some weird image dimensions jut add `<?php add_image_size( 'weird-slider-main-image', 634, 74, true ); ?>` and then all you need is to call it `<?php 
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
              the_post_thumbnail( 'weird-slider-main-image' );
            } 
            ?>`

Comment: Oh and one last note. If you add this function to an existing site your thumbnails **will not be regenerated for past images**, but you can use [Ajax Thumbnail Rebuild plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) to rebuild the thumbnails for **all** the uploaded images

Comment: Is there a reason this would only adjust the height and not the width?  That's what it's doing with mine it seems.  It is also failing to crop the images, it is just resizing them.

Comment: If you want dynamically created image sizes, I made a plugin for that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/

Comment: @DanielSachs dynamic regeneration is one of the primary reasons I prefer timthumb. Also, I don't necessarily want to use the wordpress media uploader, and rather use FTP/SCP/Git. Timthumb also supports zc=2 option which I find very useful, and different level of compression. I find the way wordpress statically stores all thumbnail sizes inefficient, whereas timthumb just caches what's actually accessed with only one source version.

Comment: @Daniel there is one limitation on this function ... which is the crops are all from the centre. This is really bad if you have a headshot (like in Lucas's picture).   However i agree this should be the best approach

Comment: @Damien. You're right, it's one of the disadvantages, among many, I guess... On the other hand it's easily addressed by editing the original file via WordPress image editing feature.

Comment: @YoavAner I have to disagree here, Yoav. Storing the the images locally may take a lot of a hardware space, but this isn't the bottle neck for most uses. CPU and Memory usually is, imho. Plus remember that [TimThumb security](http://websynthesis.com/timthumb-fiasco/) breach back in January? This is serious. And by the way I blame us, the developers. We knew about TimThumbs vulnerabilities, but did nothing... I do think that FTP/Git upload is a nice feature with TimThumb, but it pales in my mind compared to disbandment

Comment: I don't know who's to blame, I certainly didn't know about the vulnerability until it was published. The vulnerability was fixed, so I don't see this as a reason not to use timthumb, in a same way that wordpress has vulnerabilities, but it's not a good-enough reason to stop using it completely. As for the pros and cons of each approach, there isn't a silver bullet and it's fine. I prefer the dynamic aspects of timthumb and the DRY aspect of storing only one image (and not having to re-hash them when you change thumb size in your theme). Others may have different priorities.

Comment: @YoavAner Most certainly. I didn't know either, but as a concept TimThumb "invites" such attacks, imho. This is what we, as developers, supposed to know. This isn't the reason for me not to use it, obviously, - only as a side note. I completely support your approach of "to each his own", but I think that, in general, the native function has less disadvantages.

Answer (score 6):

WordPress image handling, without question.

The *only* thing that TimThumb has that is currently not possible with core image handling is **zoom crop**. Everything else can be accomplished using core image handling, *including on-the-fly resizing*.

I see absolutely no advantage to using TimThumb, and only disadvantages. It was a great tool prior to WordPress 2.9, but has been essentially unnecessary since then.

**EDIT**

Advantages to using core system:

1. Familiar UI (Media Manager, "Featured Image" metabox), rather than custom fields
2. Implement in template using core WordPress functions
3. Less overhead
4. Cross-Theme support
5. Thumbnail image handling remains extensible via Plugin
6. Thumbnail image handling maintains forward-compatibility with WordPress core

Comment: Actually you can hook custom crop on top of core functionality, it's just more messy than usual. I have answered [question about such](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20923/how-can-i-make-add-image-size-crop-from-the-top/) recently.

Comment: @Rarst can that do *zoom-crop*? If so: checkmate.

Comment: yep, dimensions for source and target areas do not need to match.

Comment: I know all WooThemes still use timthumb for dynamic image requests. But one downside is that some CDN's don't support origin-pull so timthumb never sends the image :(

Answer (score 5):

**Timthumb's ONLY advantage** is in reducing the quantity of files stored on the server.  By default Wordpress creates 3 images from each upload.  If you add additional sizes it will create a new image file for each of those as well.

Basic Usage:
1000 Posts with an average of 5 images per post will produce a minimum of 15,000 images.

Using 5 custom sizes for the crop value used in post listings, etc...
1000 Posts with an average of 5 images per post will produce a minimum of 40,000 images.

Shared hosting environments can limit the number of files on a server to 50,000 or less... thus the helpful use of timthumb which would keep the files stored lower.

That's my 2 cents....

Answer (score 4):

I choose the third option:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-image-sizes/

It generates custom thumbnail sizes on the fly, while still being integrated into WordPress.

Really, with that plugin around, you should never need to use TimThumb again.

Comment: The thing I like about this: ease of use.  The thing I hate: it's not hard-coded into the theme.

Comment: I'm sure you could safely bundle it in a theme, with a little thought.