# Why WordPress developer still using timthumb and what are advantages using them?

Tags: theme-development, timthumb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is your take: TimThumb vs. WordPress Thumbnails? The great debate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21634/what-is-your-take-timthumb-vs-wordpress-thumbnails-the-great-debate)

Can you explain to me why timthumb is much better than WP image resizer inside wp core function?

Any other image manipulation script?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its some what of an old (bad) habit of developers from back when WordPress did not have thumbnail functionality or the [**add_image_size()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function that can be used to create custom image size.

The only thing that timthumb does better is side to side cropping instead of the WordPress built-in center box cropping.

Don't get me wrong timtumb is still good but needs a little work for better security
with that being said there is a new fork called [**WordThumb**](http://code.google.com/p/wordthumb/) which works in the same way but without the vulnerability.

and if you are looking for a total different approach alternative then check out [**phpThumb**](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Aren't those arguments that you pass as href a vulnerability too? I mean anyone can mess with your server CPU by requesting resizing of the same image like 2353253265226 times, running filters on it and what not