# Set custom name for generated thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Is there any filter available to set the naming convention of those auto generated thumbnails?

Something like this:

- thumbnail_150x150.jpg -> thumbnail-s.jpg
- thumbnail_300x300.jpg -> thumbnail-m.jpg
- thumbnail_600x600.jpg -> thumbnail-l.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Seems* that the answer is **no**...

I've followed the core functions and found a dead-end. And found this post ( [How can I make add_image_size() crop from the top?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20923/12615) ) where [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) says:

> Intermediate image generation is extremely rigid. Image_resize() keeps it close to code and completely lacks hooks.

**But**, following the lead of the other answer (from [bradt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/13290/bradt)) and the code he published ( [Image Crop Position in WordPress](http://bradt.ca/archives/image-crop-position-in-wordpress/) ), I think I got it :)

In the function `bt_generate_attachment_metadata`, I've just modified the call to `bt_image_make_intermediate_size` including the last parameter `$size`

```
$resized = bt_image_make_intermediate_size( $file, $size_data['width'], $size_data['height'], $size_data['crop'], $size );
```

And modified the beggining of the function `bt_image_make_intermediate_size` as follows:

- added the `$size` parameter to the function
- instead of the default `null` value to `$suffix`, a `switch` to our new suffixes

```
function bt_image_make_intermediate_size( $file, $width, $height, $crop = false, $size ) {
    if ( $width || $height ) {
        switch($size) {
            case 'thumbnail':
                $suffix = 't';
                break;
            case 'medium':
                $suffix = 'm';
                break;
            case 'large':
                $suffix = 'l';
                break;
            default:
                $suffix = null;
                break;
        }
        $resized_file = bt_image_resize( $file, $width, $height, $crop, $suffix, null, 90 );
```

<strike>[Here](http://pastebin.com/B4cHwm3Y)</strike> , a copy of the full code with my mods, just for reference.
And the [diff from the original](http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=uyqmG6vX).

[2021]
I reviewed the code to fix the following warnings, (h/t @meek2100): two WP functions were deprecated and there's a PHP 8 notice about named parameters.
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/a0a9d485d2f0f65dcabed8519796fa67) with the changes annotated on code.

Comment: sorry, still traveling. I'll test it soon and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? It's been a few years, so...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the filter **image_make_intermediate_size**, but you would have to figure out what name you want to change the intermediate file to, according to the $filename you get (and then rename the file, because at this point it already has been generated).

I only generate an intermediate size image for the "thumbnail", so it is as simple as this:

```
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', function( $filename ) {

    // old 2017_234783843-100x100.jpg
    $old = $filename;
    // new 2017_234783843-thumbnail.jpg
    $new = preg_replace("/(\d+_\d+)-\d+x\d+\.(.*)/i", "$1-thumbnail.$2", $old );

    rename($old, $new);

    return $new;
} );
```

Comment: regex could be less specific `"/(.*)-\d+x\d+\.(.*)/i"`