# How to change the naming of the resized image files

Tags: post-thumbnails, media, images

Now with custom image sizes Wordpress is almost as powerful as timThumb / phpThumb. There is one problem however. The way Wordpress handles the resized images are chaotic and doesn't survive theme changes / image size changes.

The problem is that wordpress names the files like: `image-600x400.jpg`, instead of naming them `image-medium.jpg` or `image-custom.jpg`.

**Is it possible to override this behaviour?** It would finally make Wordpress manage image sizes perfectly! You would just need to regenerate your thumbnails with any regenerator plugin, but your URL's would all work! (Also the size information should be removed from the posts.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set custom name for generated thumbnails](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51920/set-custom-name-for-generated-thumbnails)

Comment: @brasofilo Even if the "goal" _seems_ to be the same, I guess the point is that the other images should then be _automatically_ used by the "new"/next theme.

Comment: @kaiser, oh, and that brings an interesting aspect to overcome... Hope the Q don't gets closed then... zsero, if the other Q code is useful, incorporate it here.

Comment: @brasofilo We as well got the power to reopen the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter hook [`sanitize_file_name`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_file_name) for change the string. But I have no knowing about the check for the size image, but you get the string and can check for the values inside the string.