# How to custom crop each image size?

Tags: plugins, images

I have over 6 image sizes, Therefore WP cannot satisfy every size with proper cropping as some images get their head cut off and some don't.

Is there a plugin that lets me choose the cropping area of each size (including custom sizes)?

To further explain this, I imagine it'd just let me move the crop selection for every single size.

Is there such solution?

Comment: Did you try [Post Thumbnail Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an exact duplicate but will mark it as such... Check the code provided by bradt in his answer to this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20923/12615

Comment: @Aahan Krish Thank you! that plugin was very helpful, Can you post an answer so I can accept yours?

Comment: I think that's what you are looking for:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/manual-image-crop/

Comment: You can use this plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoimages/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoimages/) (I'm the author of the plugin)

Comment: In 2023 Crop Thumbnails fits the requirements. https://wordpress.org/plugins/crop-thumbnails/

Answer (score 5):

You can customize or change WordPress image sizes using this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

The `$crop` parameter can be set to `false` for proportional or `true` for hard crop (it will hard crop from the center).

If you use this function on already existing images you will need to [regenerate them.](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/&ei=z_C3T6vhKoflggeY443ECg&usg=AFQjCNHQqSMYdcYVHOJ6vRTABqzdRsBP4A&sig2=CPU5gJLsduAl9pqUI5XAww)

If you want to manually crop individual images you can do this by default in the WordPress image editor, or use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/crop

If you are not comfortable with the above function you can use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/

To manually crop each image, click "edit" under the image in the pop-up image editor and you will see this.

[image]

To programmatically change the crop area, you will have to use a technique seen in brasofilo comment link.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of that, but I'm looking to manually choose the cropping area for each image.

Comment: I updated my answer, it is unclear if you want to manually crop each image , or bulk change the crop area through a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct WordPress to always crop some specific sizes of the image to a specific position, for example, the top of the image, so the heads of people not to be cut off in the thumbnail.

There are plugins that allow you to do that manually, for each image, and also plugins that make that automatically for every image you upload, like Image Regenerate & Select Crop. This plugin handles all sort of options for images, and it is super easy to use, the interface is very intuitive and gives you a lot of details and control over the images. Check this out at https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-regenerate-select-crop/