# Cropping images from top center using Jetpack Photon

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, plugin-jetpack

I am setting up a website gallery where the uploaded screenshot is 1400px wide and height varies.

On my post index page, I need to display a thumbnail of only 900 pixels by 600 pixels. However this is cropped from center/center. Is there a way to crop the image from top center?

There is a similar ticket [How can I make add_image_size() crop from the top?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20923/how-can-i-make-add-image-size-crop-from-the-top) but am unable to understand it.

Also I have activated the plugin Jetpack's Photon module which serves images from the WordPress cloud. It takes the URL and the size and converts it into

http://i0.wp.com/flattrendz.com/wp-content/uploads/symbolset.jpg?resize=900,600 and the original image is http://flattrendz.com/wp-content/uploads/symbolset.jpg.

Any knows how to make this photon module crop image from top center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discussed about this issue [in the WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-photon-with-different-resizing-on-different-pages). Here is a code that should do the trick:

```
/* 
 * Let's add support for Photon - that won't be necessary once Jetpack 2.3.2 is out. 
 * You'll be able to use apply_filters( 'jetpack_photon_url'... directly
 * See http://jetpack.me/2013/07/11/photon-and-themes/
 */
if( function_exists( 'jetpack_photon_url' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'jetpack_photon_url', 'jetpack_photon_url', 10, 3 );
}

/* 
 * Let's add resized post thumbnails
 * We use a different size on single pages
 */
function jeherve_display_custom( $content, $post ) {
    global $post;

    // If you didn't define a post thumnail, let's forget about all this
    if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
        return $content;

    // What's the cropping and the size of image we should use on Single pages? Here we crop to top center and create a 500 x 500px image
    // See http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/api/#crop for parameters
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $args = array(
            'crop'   => '30,0,40,50',
            'resize'   => '500,500',
        );
    }
    // resizing on other pages - some random resizing here
    else {
        $args = array(
            'resize'   => '200,400',
        );
    }

    // Let's create a Photon Image URL from the Post Thumbnail
    $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    $photon_image_url = jetpack_photon_url( $feat_image_url[0], $args );

    // Let's build the image tag, as it was built before in your example
    $our_image = sprintf( '<div class="post-media"><a class="featured-image" href="%1$s" title="%2$s"><img src="%3$s" class="wp-post-image" alt="Featured Image"></a></div>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Open %s', 'dot' ), get_the_title() ) ),
        esc_attr( $photon_image_url )
    );

    // Let's return the image, right before the post content
    return $our_image . $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'jeherve_display_custom' );
```

Here is an example, with the single page crop mentioned above:

- [Original Grid image](http://i1.wp.com/test.wpne.ws/_wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/grid.png)
- [Smaller image using the arguments I noted above](http://i1.wp.com/test.wpne.ws/_wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/grid.png?crop=30,0,40,50&resize=500,500)

For reference, you can check the Photon API documentation available [here](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/api/).